# 2D/Top Down Enemy Follow

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my Enemies follow the player in a simple top down 2D fighting game in Unity

At the moment, the following script seems is not working for 2D, as the enemies "Flip" to face the player and also seem to be behaving in 3D. What is a simple alternative to make the enemies follow the player?

LookAt is causing the issues here i think..

```
     transform.LookAt(Player);


 if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position,Player.position) >= MinDist)
 {
     transform.position += transform.forward*MoveSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to construct a vector from enemy to player and make the enemy move along it:

```
transform.position += (player.transform.position - transform.position).normalized * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
```